# Getting Project does not exist while calling a bitbucket server api version 1.0

Tags: bitbucket-server

I am using bitbucket server in my local.And trying to get all the branches using bitbucket rest API version 1.0.

http://10.0.75.1:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/coe/repos/onlinebanking/branches

Getting this error :

{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Project coe does not exist.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.project.NoSuchProjectException"}

Even the project and repository are presents with same name.what can be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

project key need to be use in place of project name in API